# Is it right to remove Guest from "deny access to this computer from the network"?

Tags: windows-7

I have a share for Everyone on a computer in a domain and I'm trying to access it from a local user on a non-domain computer. It prompts for password.

First, I followed this instruction: http://techtonis.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/windows-file-share-with-anonymous-logonaccess/ , tweaked these:

`Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users: enabled`
`Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously: '\\MYHOST\share'`

It didn't help. Then I REVERTED those settings back and instead did 2 things:

`deny access to this computer from the network: ''`
enabled Guest account.

Now it works, but can the enabled Guest do any harm now?

Answer (score 1):

Guest is the credentials your unknown account on a non-domain computer is going to use when accessing this share.  It has very low permissions.

That's not the same thing as saying people can't exploit guest.  Security auditors won't like it, either.  And any share on that machine that you've marked "Everyone" will now be open to "guest," while with guest disabled "Everyone" is only valid, authenticated accounts.

If you only have the one non-domain user, it would probably be better to create an account on the machine with the share with an identical username and password.  If there are 50+, you're probably doomed to have to use Guest or make them enter a username and password.

Comment: Is there any difference between guest and anonymous access? Why empty `Shares that can be accessed anonymously` not blocking access to `\\MYHOST\share`?